# Missing Ripple target devices in Visual Studio 2015 Cordova

Tags: .net, cordova, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I've basically spent whole my day trying to run clients app on some of the emulators, without success. I have tried Xamarin Android Player, some built in emulators I had, but all I was able to get is running emulator, without started application.

I wanted to try using Cordova emulator, so I have installed all necessary things:

[image]
[image]

After that I have realized that I still see old emulators, but no Ripple.
So I found this solution:

1. Close all Visual Studio instances
2. go to "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools" folder
3. Rename the CoreCon folder
4. Launch Visual Studio again

I did that, but all that have happened was that I lost old emulators, Ripple is still missing.

[image]

In settings I don't see anything related to Cordova.

[image]

And old emulators are gone since I have changed folder name.

[image]

Anybody had similar problems? I basically have no clue what to do, since this is my first time working with Xamarin.

Comment: Did you install Chrome in your device? If not, please try install chrome. Ripple is a chrome-based emulator.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Yes I use Chrome. The problem was solved after uninstalling VisualStudio and reinstalling it...

Comment: OK, glad to know the problem is resolved :)